# Sudo Command Node Webkit

Tags: sudo, node-webkit

How can I execute a command in Node Webkit using sudo privileges? I am trying to change permissions on files in node as well as creating directories in locations that require sudo.

Answer (score 0):

With nodejs you can execute commands in shell with a child process and the exec function. 
Here is the documentation: 
http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Example:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child;

child = exec('sudo chown -R username:group /home/myuser/myfolder',
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

Now you have stdout, stdint which are streams and you can write your password by writing it to the stream like this:

```
child.stdin.write("mypassword");
```

You can also check out this module for using sudo commands: 
https://www.npmjs.org/package/sudo